# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest and NSURLConnection initWithRequest return different data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsurlconnection

I was using     `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {}]` to return some XML data but the files got so big that a simple `UIActivityIndicator` wasn't the best idea any more.  I moved to `[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: delegate:` so that I could keep track of the progress and use a `UIProgressView` instead

I am having problems now with the new delegate code returning data before the end of the file resulting in this error from `GDataXML`
*Entity: line 85: parser error : Premature end of data in tag text line 85
igured to accept a range of values, and up to a certain number of decimal places*

If I run

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%i", [data length]);
}];
```

It writes to console: 17514

When I instead run

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

I get a different length response.  My Delegate method is:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"%i", [data length]);
}
```

3802 is printed to the console followed by 13712

Does anybody know what is going wrong here?

Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `connection:didReceiveData:` you must append the result to an `NSMutableData` instance to collect the entire response. From the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` docs, regarding the `data` parameter for this method:

> The newly available data. The delegate should concatenate the contents
>   of each data object delivered to build up the complete data for a URL
>   load.

As an example:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.mutableResponseData appendData:data];
}
```

Once the connection has finished loading the data, parse the data, e.g.:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   [self parse:self.mutableResponseData];
}
```

Comment: Thankyou this solved the problem.  Is there any reason this isn't properly documented in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html.  It is confusing as a lot of the functions there are listed as being deprecated since 4.3

Comment: The method is now part of `NUSRLConnectionDataDelegate` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection:didReceiveData:

Comment: So do I still do [connection setDelegate:self] and in the .h file set it as a <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>.  This is weird to me as it seems logical that the delegate of a NSURLConnection would be a NSURLConnectionDelegate